# How to run more logic after user registration in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the default user registrar in Laravel 5. When the user registers there is some information stored in the session so after the user has been created I want to run some code to process the session data, store it and link it to the user. Would I just amend the create method in the registrar from this:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);
}
```

to this:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);

    // do my other logic to process session data here

    return $user;
}
```

Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect opportunity for firing an event, or using the command bus.

Comment: OK, apologies in advance I've got a lot of experience with PHP with codeigniter and cakephp but I'm new to Laravel. I've just done a bit of reading up and watched a tutorial on events and that seems to be exactly what I need to do so thanks for the pointer. So I know how to create the event now using artisan but where would I put the code to trigger it? Would it be where my comment is in my example code?

Comment: No sweat, we're all beginner's at first. I certainly know there are plenty of things in Laravel I can't use yet. :) Personally, I would fire the event from the controller, so if your code sample is from the controller, where the comment is sounds great as you suggested.

Comment: My code sample is from the app/services/registrar.php file. I've tried doing it that way but my event isn't firing for some reason

Comment: Ah, right... haven't used the built-in authentication system in L5, so I can't really advise on that, I'm afraid.

Comment: ok no worries thanks for your help so far anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a model event, place this code in your model.

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::created(function($model)
    {
        //do other logic here
    });
}
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events

You can also opt for a model observer:

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class UserObserver {

    public function created(Eloquent $model)
    {
        //do other logic
    }
}
```

You'll need a listener to this observer:

```
\App\User::observe(new \App\Observers\UserObserver);
```

You can place the listener in the `routes.php` file to test it.

Later on you can move the listener to a more appropriate location such as a `ServiceProvider`.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers